# knockout "with" binding: each property to multiple controls

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Within "with" binding div, I tried to bind 5 properties of a model to 2 different types of controls, namely textbox and label. However, only the first property on the list is bound to two controls, the rest are only bound to textbox:

```
    <div data-bind="with: RetrieveObject">
      <input type= "text" data-bind="value: property1" /> <br />
      <input type= "text" data-bind="value: property2" /> <br />
      <input type= "text" data-bind="value: property3" /> <br />
      <input type= "text" data-bind="value: property4" /> <br />
      <input type= "text" data-bind="value: property5" /> <br />
      <label data-bind="text: property1" /> <br />
      <label data-bind="text: property2" /> <br />
      <label data-bind="text: property3" /> <br />
      <label data-bind="text: property4" /> <br />
      <label data-bind="text: property5" /> <br />
    </div>
```

Object is populated dynamically, meaning its properties are assigned dynamically. In my view model, I have Object = ko.observable() . And once user clicked some button, I have Object(createModel1()) executed, where createModel1 returns a new Model1. Model1 has properties defined as ko.observable.

I don't know whether this is not supposed to work or am I doing something else wrong (barking at the wrong tree)

Please help! Thank you!!!

```
    //In my viewmodel file I have the following
        window.testApp.ViewModel = (function (ko, datacontext) {
            var searchKey1 = ko.observable(),
                searchKey2 = ko.observable(),
                RetrievedObject = ko.observable(),
                CreatedObject = ko.observable(),
                error = ko.observable(),
                findObject = function () {
                datacontext.findObject(CreatedObject, RetrievedObject, searchKey1 , searchKey2, error);}
            return {
                searchKey1: searchKey1,
                searchKey2: searchKey2,
                RetrievedObject: RetrievedObject,
                CreatedObject: CreatedObject,
                error: error,
                findObject: findObject
            };

        })(ko, testApp.datacontext);
ko.applyBindings(window.testApp.ViewModel);

    //In my datacontext file, I have the following

        window.textApp = window.testApp || {};

        window.textApp.datacontext = (function () {

            var datacontext = {
                findObject: findObject,
            };

            return datacontext;

            function findObject(createdObjectObservable, retrievedObjectObservable, searchKey1Observable, searchKey2Observable, errorObservable) {
                return ajaxRequest("get", findObjectUrl(searchKey1Observable, searchKey2Observable))
                    .done(getSucceeded)
                    .fail(getFailed);

                function getSucceeded(data) {
                    var retrievedObject = new datacontext.retriveObject(data);
                    retrivedObjectObservable(retrivedObject);
                    createdObjectObservable(datacontext.createObject(policyInfo));
                }

                function getFailed() {
                    errorObservable("Invalid Policy Number or Location Zip Code.");
                }
            }
            function createObject(retrivedObject) {
                return new datacontext.createdObject(retrivedObject);
            }
        //private
            function clearErrorMessage(entity) { entity.errorMessage(null); }
            function ajaxRequest(type, url, data, dataType) { // Ajax helper
                var options = {
                    dataType: dataType || "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    cache: false,
                    type: type,
                    data: data ? data.toJson() : null
                };
                var antiForgeryToken = $("#antiForgeryToken").val();
                if (antiForgeryToken) {
                    options.headers = {
                        'RequestVerificationToken': antiForgeryToken
                    }
                }
                return $.ajax(url, options);
            }
            // routes
             function findObjectUrl(key1, key2) { return "/api/Stuff/GetStuff/?Key1=" + (key1() || "") + "&key2=" + (key2() || ""); }

        })();

//in my models file, I have following:
(function (ko, datacontext) {
    datacontext.createdObject = createdObject
    datacontext.retrievedObject = retrievedObject;

    function createdObject(data) {
        var self = this;
        data = data || {};
        self.property1 = ko.observable(data.property1);
        self.property2 = ko.observable(data.property2);
        self.property3 = ko.observable(data.property3);
        self.property4 = ko.observable(data.property4);
        self.property5 = ko.observable(data.property5);
        self.property6 = ko.observable();
        self.property7 = ko.observable();
        self.property8 = ko.observable();       
        self.errorMessage = ko.observable();
        self.toJson = function () { return ko.toJSON(self) };
    };

    function retrievedObject(data) {
        var self = this;
        data = data || {};
        self.property1 = ko.observable(data.property1);
        self.property2 = ko.observable(data.property2);
        self.property3 = ko.observable(data.property3);
        self.property4 = ko.observable(data.property4);
        self.property5 = ko.observable(data.property5);
        self.errorMessage = ko.observable();
        self.toJson = function () { return ko.toJSON(self) };
    };
})(ko, testApp.datacontext);
```

Comment: Are you facing any issues? Any errors?

Comment: Is it possible to put up fiddle ?

Comment: @AshReva When the page is rendered, only the five inputs and first label is displayed

Comment: Have you checked if there are any errors in console? I am sure there will be some errors and thats why it is rendering till 1st lable

Comment: @AshReva I didn't see any errors on console, but I will set a break point and step through, Meanwhile there is something that I am not sure is legible to do: self.property1 = ko.observable(data.property1); should it be self.property1 = ko.observable(data.property1()); Since data and data's properties in function createObject(data) are an observable by themselves. Thanks!

Comment: If you are able to print property1 to 5 in textbox then you should also be able to bind the same to lable because you are using with binding and all your controls are under those bindings. So should not give any problems

Comment: you should use this.property1 = ko.observable(data.property1) instead of self.property1

Comment: @AshReva The strange thing was if I order the controls as following:input(prop1) , label(prop1), input(pro2), input(pro3).... Then only the first two controls are displayed

Comment: what if you remove all lables and just bind textboxes? What if you just keep lables and remove textboxes?

Comment: Also what data do you get in RetrievedObject ? Have you checked it?

Comment: @AshReva outputs are fine if I do what you suggest. My observation is, when binding are repeated(by repeat, I meant binding one property to multiple control), controls are displayed fine up to the first repeat.

Comment: can you put up fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just that HTML label element requires an end tag.  In other words the following is not valid:

```
<label data-bind="text: property1" />
```

It should be

```
<label data-bind="text: property1" ></label>
```

Also the HTML has a spelling error on the with statement.  It should be "RetrievedObject".